# Automated background E-mail ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I´m trying to add a new feature to a project I´m currently working on.

The idea is that, when certain variable gets a value the application sends an automated email to a mailbox as a warning notification.

I did some research about SmtpClient and I believe that is the best approach to add this new feature, but I have some unsolved matters that I would like to get some advise:

- Prevent email spamming: I want this email to be sent just once per event change.
- Email body building: How should I build the emails body.
- Smtp clients: Is it possible to use multiple Smtp Clients?

Thats all guys, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

•Prevent email spamming: I want this email to be sent just once per event change. 
If it is a background event then how can it be used for spamming? Your users wouldn't know about this feature, When your event is triggered the email will be sent.

•Email body building: How should I build the emails body.
Email body can be any string, so you can create whatever string and send that.

•Smtp clients: Is it possible to use multiple Smtp Clients?

It is just an object, so you can create as many as you like, but one should be all you need.

Here is smtp code that might help you..

```
            var fromAddress = "no.reply@fsdfds.com";
            var toAddress = "email@something.com";
    var subject = "something";
    const string fromPassword = "";
            string body = "Welcome.." + DateTime.Today;
            // smtp settings
            var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                smtp.Port = 25;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                smtp.Timeout = 600000;
            }
            // Passing values to smtp object
                smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```

Comment: What about this line `smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";` ; I can send emails to any kind of email even though it has that format? e.g: marcelo@whateveriwant.com.
Also about the spamming topic, I have got a cache that refreshes every 15 seconds, that´s why I´m worried about the email spamming, but I think is more like a logic matter that I need to handle.

Comment: The host is the email provider(where the emails be sent from) This example works with Office365.  You will have to adopt the code a bit for gmail.  Yeah you will be send emails to any valid email address.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, if it answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry This ID not the answer, i'm looking for something like a Windows Service but i cannot create one since i'm working on visual studio community edition and template doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table in your database, and have a background worker to handle the email-sending-process. This way you can run it every 10 minute, and only send mails if theres anything new in the table. And when you send it, you can combine every event within the last 10 minutes in one message..
2. The body can just be plain text..
3. Like running it in a thread or what do you mean?

Comment: About 3) I´m sorry...I do not know what is a thread, but I have seen that SmtpClient examples harcode smtp.gmail.com on the smtpclient and I might work with a different smtp and just wanted to know.

Comment: If you don't know what a thread is then, no - you do not need multiple smtp servers or connections. You can reuse the first one you create, and then you can just send multiple messages with that.